# Randomly sample from multiple tf.data.Datasets in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

suppose I have *N* tf.data.Datasets and a list of *N* probabilities (summing to 1), now I would like to create dataset such that the examples are sampled from the *N* datasets with the given probabilities.

I would like this to work for arbitrary probabilities -> simple zip/concat/flatmap with fixed number of examples from each dataset is probably not what I am looking for.

Is it possible to do this in TF? Thanks!

Comment: Are you not interested in using all of the data? I am asking since if you are, the probabilities will only affect the order in which the examples are produced (as eventually all samples will be produced from all of the datasets). Could you clarify your question in this regard?

Comment: I am assuming infinite repeating of each dataset, so smaller dataset can be cycled multiple times before 'finishing' a bigger one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of 1.12, `tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets` provides this functionality:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets

EDIT: Looks like in earlier versions this can be accessed by `tf.contrib.data.sample_from_datasets`

Comment: Be very careful if the different datasets have significantly different length. In that case you will have to manually do the either the repetition of smaller datasets or truncating of longer datasets **before** you apply the `tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets` method.
For more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278214/does-tensorflows-sample-from-datasets-still-sample-from-a-dataset-when-gettin)

Comment: Is there a way to sample a single element form a dataset? If `a` is a dataset I can access the first sample with `a.take(1)`. Can I make something like `a.takerandom(1)`?

Comment: @Royi I think you may be able to achieve that by using `shuffle`, i.e. `a.shuffle(buffer_size=10).take(1)` given that `a` is of size 10.

Answer (score 4):

if `p` is a `Tensor` of probabilities (or unnormalized relative probabilities) where `p[i]` is the probability that dataset `i` is chosen, you can use `tf.multinomial` in conjunction with `tf.contrib.data.choose_from_datasets`:

```
# create some datasets and their unnormalized probability of being chosen
datasets = [
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(['a']).repeat(),
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(['b']).repeat(),
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(['c']).repeat(),
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(['d']).repeat()]
p = [1., 2., 3., 4.]  # unnormalized

# random choice function
def get_random_choice(p):
  choice = tf.multinomial(tf.log([p]), 1)
  return tf.cast(tf.squeeze(choice), tf.int64)

# assemble the "choosing" dataset
choice_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors([0])  # create a dummy dataset
choice_dataset = choice_dataset.map(lambda x: get_random_choice(p))  # populate it with random choices
choice_dataset = choice_dataset.repeat()  # repeat

# obtain your combined dataset, assembled randomly from source datasets
# with the desired selection frequencies. 
combined_dataset = tf.contrib.data.choose_from_datasets(datasets, choice_dataset)
```

Note that the dataset needs to be initialized (you can't use a simple make_one_shot_iterator):

```
choice_iterator = combined_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
choice = choice_iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(choice_iterator.initializer)
  print ''.join([sess.run(choice)[0] for _ in range(20)])

>> ddbcccdcccbbddadcadb
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but this seems to be the optimal solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/rejection_resample) to achieve target distribution.

Comment: Ok, this could work, thanks... If I understand it correctly, I would interleave the datasets uniformly and add a dataset identificator to the tensors in the dataset, then this rejection_resample would throw away elements of this big interleaved datasets in order to match the provided distribution? It seems like a very very slow and inefficient way of doing things :(

Comment: @serycjon, yes, you got it right. And yes, I think it will be inefficient.

Comment: Accepting this till somebody finds an efficient solution.

Comment: @serycjon, I can suggest more efficient solutions, but then I need to know more details. What is the source of your datasets? Is it TFRecords, just files or something else?

Comment: I know combining different datasets can be done efficiently in various ways, however, my question is just about the tf.data.Datasets -> It should not matter what is the source of the data. Let's just assume I have several Dataset objects, regardless of their source. Logically, randomly sampling from these *N* Datasets should be easily done with almost zero performance hit. The question is - is it possible in tensorflow?

Comment: @serycjon yes, using choose_from_datasets and multinomial. See my response below.