# Does TensorFlow's `sample_from_datasets` still sample from a Dataset when getting a `DirectedInterleave selected an exhausted input` warning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

When using TensorFlow's [`tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets) to equally sample from two very unbalanced Datasets, I end up getting a `DirectedInterleave selected an exhausted input: 0` warning. Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/google-research/meta-dataset/issues/7), it appears that this is occurring when one of the Datasets inside the `sample_from_datasets` has been depleted of examples, and would need to sample already seen examples.

Does the depleted dataset then still produce samples (thereby maintaining the desired balanced training ratio), or does the dataset not sample so the training once again becomes unbalanced? If the latter, is there a method to produce the desired balanced training ratio with `sample_from_datasets`?

*Note: TensorFlow 2 Beta is being used*

Comment: I would guess it is the former, but I have not found where the error is thrown from. In any case, to be safe, I would [repeat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat) the datasets with `count=None` before passing them to `sample_from_datasets`.

Comment: @rvinas, I would assume that such a `repeat` would interfere with the epoch tracking (my current setup uses the Keras `fit`), however, adding this `repeat` does *not* lead to an infinite epoch. Why it might fix the exhausted dataset but not cause a problem with the epoch seems strange to me. Though this is off topic, do you happen to know how those two pieces are related? (Unfortunately, I can't test the code for the original question just now to see if the `repeat` fixes it)

Comment: My previous comment has a mistake in it. `repeat` *does* lead to an infinite epoch for Keras' `fit`. In my test for the previous comment I mistakenly did not use `repeat`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The smaller dataset does NOT repeat - once it is exhausted the remainder will just come from the larger dataset that still has examples.

You can verify this behaviour by doing something like this:

```py
def data1():
  for i in range(5):
    yield "data1-{}".format(i)

def data2():
  for i in range(10000):
    yield "data2-{}".format(i)

ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data1, tf.string)
ds2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data2, tf.string)

sampled_ds = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([ds2, ds1], seed=1)
```

then if we iterate over `sampled_ds` we see that no samples from `data1` are produced once it is exhausted:

```
tf.Tensor(b'data1-0', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-0', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-1', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-2', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-3', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-4', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data1-1', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data1-2', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data1-3', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-5', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data1-4', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-6', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-7', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-8', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-9', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-10', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-11', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'data2-12', shape=(), dtype=string)
...
---[no more 'data1-x' examples]--
...
```

Of course, you *could* make `data1` repeat with something like this:

```py
sampled_ds = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([ds2, ds1.repeat()], seed=1)
```

but it seems from comments that you are aware of this and it doesn't work for your scenario.

> If the latter, is there a method to produce the desired balanced training ratio with sample_from_datasets?

Well, if you have 2 datasets of differing lengths and you are sampling evenly from then it seems like you only have 2 choices:

- repeat the smaller dataset `n` times (where `n ≃ len(ds2)/len(ds1)`)
- stop sampling once the smaller dataset is exhausted

To achieve the first you can use `ds1.repeat(n)`.

To achieve the second you could use `ds2.take(m)` where `m=len(ds1)`.

Comment: This API is dangerous to ML training. Because it samples all datasets to completion, the final batches will come entirely from one source dataset. Even if you try to take() the correct number so that you could blend smoothly, the fact that is stochastic once again means the final batch will be skewed, which will really mess up any mini-batch based training.